# having a Valgrind error

Tags: valgrind

I have a question about valgrind. In the following function, I don't see any errors but when I run a Valgrind test, it shows an error.

Can someone please tell me what I should do to make it work correctly?

```
char * anfuegen(char * teilvorne, char * teilhinten)
{
    size_t laengeTeilvorne = strlen(teilvorne);
    size_t laengeTeilhinten = strlen(teilhinten);

    char * neuerDateiname = (char*) malloc(
        laengeTeilvorne + laengeTeilhinten + 1);

    memcpy(neuerDateiname, teilvorne, laengeTeilvorne);
    memcpy(neuerDateiname + laengeTeilvorne, teilhinten, laengeTeilhinten + 1);

    return neuerDateiname;
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  You've told us that Valgrind gives you an error, but you don't show what it says.  That makes it hard to guess what your problem is.  The information from `valgrind` is very good; it tells you the line number where the problem is (assuming you have compiled with `-g` for debugging output — and if you haven't, you're wasting `valgrind`).  You should check the return value from `malloc()` before using it.

Comment: it shows this error : ==24094== by 0x804954C: anfuegen (1373051401.c:642)

Comment: That is not the error, it is part of the stack trace at the point of the error.

Comment: It's also not a complete error. And which line is 642?